# Where is "Refactor Fields"?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgis-processing

I need to change the name of a field in an attribute table. I just installed QGIS 2.18.3. I understand that I should now use "Refactor Fields" instead of Table Manager. I don't see it anywhere, including in my Toolbox under Processing. I understand that I may need to be in the Advanced Interface mode. However, I don't see how to get into it. It is not at the bottom of my Toolbox, as I have seen mentioned.

Comment: No need advanced mode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is ["Refactor fields"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) instead of *"Refractor"*. You will find this in *Processing Toolbox* under *QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector table tools > Refactor fields*.

Since a few versions of QGIS now by default there is only one common interface mode for *Processing toolbox*.

Comment: I guess this tool is available in newer versions of qgis and not in older versions any idea about alternatives for older versions? I want to rearrange the position of fields using pyqgis.